# Julia: How to count efficiently the number of missings in a `Vector{Union{T, Missing}}`

Tags: julia

Consider

```
x = rand([missing, rand(Int, 100)...], 1_000_000)
```

which yields `typeof(x)` = `Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}`.

What's the most efficient way to count the number of missings in `x`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably just

```
count(ismissing, x)
```

Simple, easy to remember, and fast

Since you're asking for the "most efficient" way, let me give some benchmark results. It is slightly faster than @xiaodai's answer, and as fast as a simple loop implementation:

```
julia> @btime count($ismissing,$x);
  278.499 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime mapreduce($ismissing, $+, $x);
  293.901 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime count_missing($x)
  278.499 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

where

```
julia> function count_missing(x)
           c = 0
           @inbounds for i in eachindex(x)
               if ismissing(x[i])
                   c += 1
               end
           end
           return c
       end
```

Abstraction for no cost, just the way you'd want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your number of missing is less than 4 billion elements (or less than 65k elements) you can be several times faster than @crstnbr answer with the following code:

```
function count_missing(x, T)
    c = zero(T)
    for i in 1:length(x)
        c += @inbounds ismissing(x[i])
    end
    return Int(c)  #we want to have stable result type
                   # this could be further combined with a barrier function
                   # that could check the size of `x` at the runtime
end
```

Now the benchmarks.

This is the original time on my laptop:

```
julia> @btime count_missing($x, Int)
  227.799 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes) 
9971
```

Slash the time by half if you know there is less than 4 billion matching elements:

```
julia> @btime count_missing($x, UInt32)
  113.899 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
9971
```

Slash the time by 8x if you know there is less than 65k matching elements:

```
julia> @btime count_missing($x, UInt16)
  29.200 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
9971
```

Comment: @xiaodai - for most cases it is more natural to return `Int` rather than `T`. In particular the default way the terminal displays other values - try typing in the terminal ` UInt32(15)` and see what happens.

Comment: You could also have written this as `mapreduce(ismissing, +, x, init=T(0))`, which is just as fast and is what `count` actually calls under the hood. I just opened a PR to add the ability to pass the `init` argument to `count` directly: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/37461

Comment: Actually the speedup due to using a small integer type seems to happen only in this particular case of counting missing values, and it doesn't appear when counting *non-missing* values. It might be due to a compiler limitation. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/37461#issuecomment-689395105

Answer (score 0):

This is an unsafe answer and is not guaranteed to work in future if Julia changes the memory layout but it's fun

```
x = Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}(missing, 100_000_000)
x[rand(1:100_000_000, 90_000_000)] .= rand.()

using BenchmarkTools

@benchmark count($ismissing, $x)
# BenchmarkTools.Trial:
#   memory estimate:  0 bytes
#   allocs estimate:  0
#   --------------
#   minimum time:     48.468 ms (0.00% GC)
#   median time:      51.755 ms (0.00% GC)
#   mean time:        66.863 ms (0.00% GC)
#   maximum time:     91.449 ms (0.00% GC)
#   --------------
#   samples:          76
#   evals/sample:     1

function unsafe_count_missing(x::Vector{Union{Missing, T}}) where T
    @assert isbitstype(T)
    l = length(x)
    GC.@preserve x begin
        y = unsafe_wrap(Vector{UInt8}, Ptr{UInt8}(pointer(x) + sizeof(T)*l), l)
        res = reduce(-, y; init = l)
    end
    res
end

@time count(ismissing, x) == unsafe_count_missing(x)

@benchmark faster_count_missing($x)
# BenchmarkTools.Trial:
#   memory estimate:  80 bytes
#   allocs estimate:  1
#   --------------
#   minimum time:     9.190 ms (0.00% GC)
#   median time:      9.718 ms (0.00% GC)
#   mean time:        9.845 ms (0.00% GC)
#   maximum time:     15.691 ms (0.00% GC)
#   --------------
#   samples:          508
#   evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Actually it turns out you can get the same level of performance using the more generic approach given by @crstnbr above, but computing the number of *non-missing* values. For some reason the compiler generates more efficient code in that case. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37473